# What does the init command do?

Tags: javascript, node.js, linux, unix, jasmine

Several Node.js packages have the following two steps as their starting point (just using [Jasmine](https://jasmine.github.io/pages/getting_started.html) as an example):

```
npm install --save-dev jasmine
./node_modules/.bin/jasmine init
```

The first statement is straightforward, but I could not for the life of me figure out what the second statement does under the hood. The Jasmine docs only say that it initializes it (I am searching for something more technical).

./node_modules/.bin/jasmine looks like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
basedir=$(dirname "$(echo "$0" | sed -e 's,\\,/,g')")

case `uname` in
    *CYGWIN*) basedir=`cygpath -w "$basedir"`;;
esac

if [ -x "$basedir/node" ]; then
  "$basedir/node"  "$basedir/../jasmine/bin/jasmine.js" "$@"
  ret=$?
else 
  node  "$basedir/../jasmine/bin/jasmine.js" "$@"
  ret=$?
fi
exit $ret
```

**In case helpful, I did this to clone and install the package locally:**

- mkdir testProj : Creates new project folder
- code testProj --add : Adds folder to workspace
- cd testProj
- npm init : Creates package.json
- npm install  [--save-dev] : Installs dependencies
- ./node_modules/.bin/ init : What does this do, specifically?

  - Short: npx  init

Any pointers/documentation explaining that init would be deeply appreciated.

**Edit:**

Just to clarify, I know *what* init does (clear from testing and the Jasmine documentation), I just do not understand *how* it does it. I am basically trying to find out why init is needed behind the script name when running it from the CLI, and where the init code is located.

Comment: It appears it's just using a shell script to call the `jasmine.js` file via node. Never really seen that as a step in any node packages personally

Comment: The code you've provided doesn't do anything with the command line arguments beyond passing them on to jamine.js when it gets called.

Comment: Probably just to normalise some paths from the basedir, but mostly innocuous imho

Comment: Yep, I hear ya, I just want to understand what it does, specifically. To follow the code and see what code is invoked when. Is init an argument sent to the code i posted? Or is it an actual function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to finally solve this myself. If anyone comes across this in the future, the following is the explanation of `./node_modules/.bin/jasmine init`.

1. `./node_modules/.bin/jasmine init` is executed from the command line
2. This runs the `jasmine` Unix script in `./node_modules/.bin/` (`init` argument is not used yet)
3. The script resolves path to `jasmine.js` (`./node_modules/jasmine/bin/jasmine.js`) and runs it
4. `Jasmine.js` contains this code: `var Command = require('../lib/command.js')`
5. `Jasmine.js` creates a new instance of the `Command` object (`command`) and executes: `command.run(jasmine, process.argv.slice(2));`

   - [process.argv](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/process.html#process_process_argv) is an array of all arguments given when starting the application from command line. Recalling the command, one sees that `slice(2)` equals `init`
6. The `run` function inside `command.js` launches `initJasmine` by having mapped `init` to `initJasmine` at the very top
7. Finally, `initJasmine` makes the directory `spec` and all its contents

Hope that helps someone else in the future.

Answer (score 0):

`jasmine init` initializes a basic folder structure for Jasmine by creating a spec directory and configuration json for you. You can look for more details here https://github.com/jasmine/jasmine-npm

Comment: Hi Alexey. I found those docs too, but it does not provide any detail on what init actually is. First I thought it was a property or function inside the bin/Jasmine file. It was not. Then I thought it might be some kind of special Unix keyword. I looked through various Unix script tutorials and only found references to init.d, which is a script used when booting linux. Any additional insight would be deeply appreciated.

Comment: `init` just creates `spec/support/jasmine.json` file and put there default configuration from examples. That's all. BTW, `node_modules/.bin/jasmine` for me looks different

Comment: Sorry, let me clarify. I know *what* init does, I just do not understand *how* it does it. Where is the "init" code that conducts those tasks? It is not just running the jasmine Unix script, as running a script from the CLI does not need any code after the script name (other than flags and arguments). Regarding your file, are you sure you are not looking at Jasmine.js? WHat i posted is not Jasmine.js, it is the Unix script inside the node_module/bin folder.